# Proof using Squeeze Theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, real-numbers

Prove that if
[image]
then if
[image]

then

[image]

I know that the squeeze theorem states that there are three real number sequences such that if two of them converge to L then the third converges to L.  In this case -1/n and 1/n are both converging to 0.  Therefore can we say that

[image] ?

Therefore,

[image]

Can someone let me know where I am off?

Comment: You didn't mention another assumption for squeeze theorem. That is for any $n$ the term $c_n$ whose limit is to be deduced must be assumed to lie between the terms $a_n$ and $b_n$ each of which has limit $L.$ And by between one can use "weak" between-ness as in $a_n \le c_n \le b_n$ or the reverse $b_n \le c_n \le a_n.$ Without assuming that relation we can't automatically arrive at $c_n \to L$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the fact that the sine function is bounded:
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{\sin(n)}{n}\right| \leq \frac{1}{n}
\end{align*}

Then, if you apply the squeeze theorem, you get that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{\sin(n)}{n}\right| \leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n} = 0 \Rightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin(n)}{n} = 0
\end{align*}
where the last relation holds because a sequence $a_{n}$ converges to zero iff $|a_{n}|$ converges to zero.

Hopefully this helps!